# AWS: Adding SSH keys for my user

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I just created an instance on AWS EC2. I got the ec2-user's pub/private keys and I'm able to login using my puTTY client from my Windows machine.

Now, I want to connect to the same instance with a new user(xxxx). For that:

- First I created a user using 'useradd' on AWS instance
- Generated pub/private keys on my windows machine using puTTYgen
- Copied pub key content to >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys file.
- Now, I'm trying to connect using puTTY by using the private key

But I'm unable to login, and I'm getting the following error:

```
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "xxxx".
Server refused our key
No supported authentication methods left to try!

Connection has been unexpectedly closed. Server sent command exit status 0.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to fix this by creating an authorized_keys file under the xxxx user home directory(`/home/xxxx/.ssh/authorized_keys`) instead of `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`